# Apache 404 on basic install

Tags: install

I am getting an Apache 404 page when trying to install Craft after following all instructions. I've run out of ideas.

- Set up a droplet running LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04 with [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com)
- 'craft' folder is sitting in public at `'var/www'` and `index.php` on
  the same level is pointing to `$craftPath = './craft';`
- `.htaccess` is running
- set folder permissions
- Created MySQL database with new user
- Updated `db.php`
- Have tried `example.com/admin` and
  `example.com/index.php/admin` and
  `example.com/index.php?p=admin`

Have tried moving craft folder above root and updating `$craftPath` but with no luck. Not sure what else to try?

Comment: If it's an Apache 404, sounds more like a vhosts problem? Like domain.dev isn't pointing to `var/www` maybe?

Comment: Thanks. This solved it for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server

Comment: Nice.  Care to add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up the document root was looking for `var/www/html` instead of just `var/www`

This fixed it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175981/851669